# using jquery and its css - want to fiddle with styling

Tags: jquery, button, css, jquery-mobile

Does anyone knows how to round off buttons in the jquery mobile css? I am using the this css to style my buttons and need to round off the corners. Someone has a clue how to do it? If you need any more information, just ask for it :)

Regards,
BG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.css(
      {'-moz-border-radius': '20px',
      '-webkit-border-radius': '20px',
      '-khtml-border-radius': '20px',
      'border-radius': '20px'}
);
```

Also for IE Issues you can use this style in css behavior: url(/css/border-radius.htc);

The above solutions is cross browser compatible.

Reference website is as follows:
http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers

Answer (score 1):

Use the following: `.css("border-radius", "10px");`

Note that this uses css3, which is not supported by IE versions older than 9 and IE9 itself doesn't fully support css3.